# portrait layout apears when the tablet is on landscape mode

Tags: android, android-layout

when I run my android app on tablet in landscape mode the apps apears from right to left (as if it is portrait mode) not up to down, how to fix that?

you can find a snapshot here:  https://i.stack.imgur.com/vpO9M.jpg

I am trying to make my app compatible with tablets I created the layout res for large screens and x large screens (layout-xlarge, layout-xlarge-land, layout-large and layout-large-land) and I added this to my androidManifest.xml file:

```
<supports-screens
    android:anyDensity="true"
    android:largeScreens="true"
    android:normalScreens="true"
    android:smallScreens="true" />
```

Comment: May be you have used a `LinearLayout` with `android:orientation="horizontal"`?

Comment: If you'd provide more information, i could help you.

Comment: I edited the question, please take a look

Comment: No I haven't Sash_KP.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding this within your activity, in your manifest.xml file

```
        android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|screenSize|layoutDirection"
```